# How to make sure a div doesn't start a new line whenever window is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a simple tic-tac-toe game for fun. Everything is working fine except whenever I resize the window, my right-most div starts a new line. Why does this happen? I have tried almost every method out there. I made a method that changes div size according to window size. I have tried the float: left. I have tried display:inline and display: inline-block. Here is my code for the pieces:

```html
            <div id = "pieces">
                <style>
                    .pieces 
                    {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        float: left;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                        overflow: auto;
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;
                        
                    }
                </style>
            <div id = "xMark" class = "x">
                X
                
                <script>
                    
                    window.addEventListener("resize", function dimensions() {
                        var textWidth = (window.innerWidth/3);
                        var textHeight = (window.innerHeight/3);
                        document.getElementById("xMark").style.height = textHeight+"px";
                        document.getElementById("xMark").style.width = textWidth+"px";
                    });
                    
                    //document._intervalId = setInterval(dimensions, 1);
                </script>
                <style>
                    .x
                    {
                        
                        
                        height: 33.333333333333vh;
                        display: inline-block;
                        
                        width:  33.333333333333vw;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        font-size: 30px;
                        border: 5px solid black;
                        text-align: center;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        overflow: auto;
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    .x:hover
                    {
                        background-color: blue;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        overflow: auto;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
            <div id = "hyphonMark" class = "hyphon">
                --
                
                <script>
                    
                    window.addEventListener("resize", function dimensions() {
                        var textWidth = (window.innerWidth/3);
                        var textHeight = (window.innerHeight/3);
                        document.getElementById("hyphonMark").style.height = textHeight+"px";
                        document.getElementById("hyphonMark").style.width = textWidth+"px";
                    });
                    //document._intervalId = setInterval(dimensions, 1);
                    
                </script>
                <style>
                    .hyphon
                    {
                        
                        height: 33.333333333333vh;
                        display: inline-block;
                        width:  33.333333333333vw;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        font-size: 30px;
                        border: 5px solid black;
                        text-align: center;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        overflow: auto;
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    .hyphon:hover
                    {
                        background-color: blue;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
            <div id = "oMark" class = "O">
                O
                
                <script>
                    
                    function dimensions() {
                        var textWidth = (window.innerWidth/3);
                        var textHeight = (window.innerHeight/3);
                        document.getElementById("oMark").style.height = textHeight+"px";
                        document.getElementById("oMark").style.width = textWidth+"px";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("oMark").addEventListener("resize", dimensions);
                    //document._intervalId = setInterval(dimensions, 1);
                    
                </script>
                <style>
                    .O
                    {
                        
                        height: 33.333333333333vh;
                        display: inline-block;
                        
                        width: 32.333333333333vw;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        font-size: 30px;
                        border: 5px solid black;
                        text-align: center;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        overflow: auto;
                        
                       
                        
                    }
                    .O:hover
                    {
                        background-color: blue;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `.pieces` (a class) to `#pieces` (the id), then your CSS will work.

```html
            <div id="pieces">
                <style>
                    #pieces 
                    {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        float: left;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                        overflow: auto;
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;
                        
                    }
                </style>
            <div id = "xMark" class = "x">
                X
                
                <script>
                    
                    window.addEventListener("resize", function dimensions() {
                        var textWidth = (window.innerWidth/3);
                        var textHeight = (window.innerHeight/3);
                        document.getElementById("xMark").style.height = textHeight+"px";
                        document.getElementById("xMark").style.width = textWidth+"px";
                    });
                    
                    //document._intervalId = setInterval(dimensions, 1);
                </script>
                <style>
                    .x
                    {
                        
                        
                        height: 33.333333333333vh;
                        display: inline-block;
                        
                        width:  33.333333333333vw;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        font-size: 30px;
                        border: 5px solid black;
                        text-align: center;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        overflow: auto;
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    .x:hover
                    {
                        background-color: blue;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        overflow: auto;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
            <div id = "hyphonMark" class = "hyphon">
                --
                
                <script>
                    
                    window.addEventListener("resize", function dimensions() {
                        var textWidth = (window.innerWidth/3);
                        var textHeight = (window.innerHeight/3);
                        document.getElementById("hyphonMark").style.height = textHeight+"px";
                        document.getElementById("hyphonMark").style.width = textWidth+"px";
                    });
                    //document._intervalId = setInterval(dimensions, 1);
                    
                </script>
                <style>
                    .hyphon
                    {
                        
                        height: 33.333333333333vh;
                        display: inline-block;
                        width:  33.333333333333vw;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        font-size: 30px;
                        border: 5px solid black;
                        text-align: center;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        overflow: auto;
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    .hyphon:hover
                    {
                        background-color: blue;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
            <div id = "oMark" class = "O">
                O
                
                <script>
                    
                    function dimensions() {
                        var textWidth = (window.innerWidth/3);
                        var textHeight = (window.innerHeight/3);
                        document.getElementById("oMark").style.height = textHeight+"px";
                        document.getElementById("oMark").style.width = textWidth+"px";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("oMark").addEventListener("resize", dimensions);
                    //document._intervalId = setInterval(dimensions, 1);
                    
                </script>
                <style>
                    .O
                    {
                        
                        height: 33.333333333333vh;
                        display: inline-block;
                        
                        width: 32.333333333333vw;
                        background-color: lightblue;
                        font-size: 30px;
                        border: 5px solid black;
                        text-align: center;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        overflow: auto;
                        
                       
                        
                    }
                    .O:hover
                    {
                        background-color: blue;
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        text-align: center;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
```